# Search for posts based on author reputation

Tags: support, data-explorer, search

I want to list all questions and answers posted based on the author's reputation.

Example: list all posts posted by users who have a reputation of more than 50 and less than 100, since these posts might possibly need to be improved.

Is there a search query or mechanism that exists for this?

Comment: What is your goal in putting together this search?

Comment: Your best bet might be to just search by score. Forget reputation. If something is downvoted, it probably needs some help. Also, you could dig through the Stack Exchange API and see if you can filter questions by author reputation. What I can tell you is that the standard advanced search tools don't support what you're trying to do.

Comment: `Because these posts are the possible eligible candidate for correction.` On what premises you're drawing this?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, others can edit such post for better formatting, re-tagging etc etc. Also by this I can search very best answers by user reputation(Although  I can do it by searching based on votes/scores). This will improve the quality of posts.

Comment: @DamienPirsy Because new users(Having less reputation) don't know(or less familiar to) how to ask, format and other rules of stack-overflow

Comment: This is not entirely a bad idea. I've wanted something similar for more refined searches for non-answers or spam to flag and remove (which are almost always left by users <50 rep). There are use cases for this, although whether those are worth the effort to add this, and potential discrimination against low-rep users it could cause, is up for debate.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a query you can use in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to do this, ordered by posts' **score**:

```sql
SELECT TOP 200 Id, Title, Body, Score
FROM Posts
WHERE PostTypeId IN (1,2) AND OwnerUserId
  IN (
    SELECT Id
    FROM Users
    WHERE Users.Reputation >= 50 AND Users.Reputation <= 100)
ORDER BY Score
```

Note: I'm not experienced in SQL. This query might not be efficient at all.

Although I'm not sure how good the correlation between users' reputations and posts' scores is.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible. We can not search by user's reputation. Because reputation has nothing to do with post's quality. Because every user starts from the bottom. And even high reputation user can post [incorrect / low quality answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1587794/1369235).

Instead of reputation why not search by [post's score](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score:100)? This will give you correct and high quality posts.

Comment: I am not completely agree with your statement. Because high reputation is the indication of a GOOD questioner or GOOD solution/answer provider in his/her area(with the tags he/she related to). Yes some times high reputation users contributes to low quality posts BUT **flagging** will prevent such posts.

Comment: Also note that there is a limitation for gaining reputation by accepted edits on posts. As per my knowledge user can gain max of **1000** reputation by suggesting good edits not more than that. That means other than posting good question/answer there no other way to get high reputation score. Again bad question(-2) and bad answer(-2) pull your reputation down.

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK - How is your comment related to this question?