# Searching for questions by users with at least x reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, questions, search

Is it possible to search for questions written by users with at least x points in reputation?

My motivation for asking is to find questions that are *relatively* well written and are *probably* not about trivial or obscure problems.

---

Searching by user-reputation is not possible, judging by answers to this:

- [Search for posts based on author reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224923/search-query-based-on-author-reputation)

---

However, I would like to open a feature requests such that it would be possible to formulate a query like this:

```
is:question votes:[-]N authorrep:2000
```

The result of which would be questions asked by users with at least 2000 reputation points.

This feature could help people who otherwise leave "angry comments on newbie question" to completely ignore these "newbie questions" if they desire to do so.

My motivation is somewhat different. I want to find questions that are hard to answer and have been written by a user with some amount of experience on this website. While the votes for a question do indicate the quality to some extent, I feel that it is not enough.

In the last couple of weeks I have been active again on Stack Overflow after a long idle period and I'm constantly finding unanswered questions from 2-4-6 years ago that have 2-4 up-votes, but after some investigation it turns out that the author is posting about some bug, that has since been resolved. Now, if the question was asked by someone who is somewhat active on the site, they would have closed the question or answered it themselves.

Ultimately, I'm finding a lot of questions that I feel do not deserve my attention or are otherwise impossible to answer because not enough details have been provided - and in some cases I vote to close such questions.

Despite the general feeling that I am observing in meta, about the network being "full of elitists" and "is hostile to newcomers" I don't share these opinions, or subscribe to these opinions fully. On the contrary, the feedback I have received on the network has improved my question-asking skills as well as question-answering skills.